# Angular 1.2: custom directive's dynamic content: ng-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do a very simple thing in Angular 1.2: I want to create dynamic content for my custom directive, and add a click handler (clickCustomer) to parts of it. However, when I do that in the following pattern, whilst the `clickCustomer` function is available on the element's scope, it is not invoked when clicking on it. I'm gussing I need to get Angular to compile the dynamic content, but I'm not sure if that's actually the case, and if it is, how to do so.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('directives.customers')
.directive('customers', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="customers"></div>',
    controller: function ($scope, $element) {
      var customers = ['Customer1', 'Customer2', 'Customer3'];
      var customersMapped = customers.map(function (customer) {
        return '<span ng-click="clickCustomer()" data-customer="' + customer + '">' + customer + '</span>';
      });
      var text = customersMapped.join(', ');
      $element.html(text);

      $scope.clickCustomer = function (event) {
        console.log('Customer clicked', event);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you need to use the `$compile` service and compile the attached DOM elements so Angular will set up the events and scopes.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samiraguiar/39saqyez/5/).